# Flutter How to get Instagram posted video/image URL from a copied/share link with shortcode via InstagramBasicDisplay

Tags: json, api, flutter, dart, instagram

Usually they use '?__a=1' to get json data but I can't get a followed 'private' media url from it. But I have the access token, is there any way or endpoint that I can refer to with access token so that they can download a media from a "FOLLOWED" private users from a copied/share link?